# Code Sandbox style is different than Chrome style

Tags: css, reactjs, codesandbox

I tested a React app design using css and bootstrap in Code Sandbox (online editor).
The problem is, when I copied the files to a real react app in my computer, the page styling is different than what I designed in code Sandbox.
Is there anything missing I have to add to my code?

The style in Sandbox..

[image]

The style in my computer browser..

[image]

Comment: Do you have any **dependencies** or **external resources** in the CodeSandbox app that are not present in your local React app? (You can view them in your project explorer in CodeSandbox, under the project files.)

Comment: No, I don't have, the all dependencies are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The problem is when uploading the files from CodeSandBox, the css file has the line,

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer- 
reset/2.0/reset.min.css");
```

removing it solved my problem.